# extra_compile_args in Cython

Tags: cython

I want to pass some extra options to the `Cython` compiler by using `extra_compile_args`.

My `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup

from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
  name = 'Test app',
  ext_modules = cythonize("test.pyx", language="c++", extra_compile_args=["-O3"]),
)
```

However, when I run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, I get the following warning:

```
UserWarning: got unknown compilation option, please remove: extra_compile_args
```

**Question:** How does one use `extra_compile_args` correctly?

I use `Cython 0.23.4` under `Ubuntu 14.04.3`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the more traditional way without `cythonize` to supply extra compiler options:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
  name = 'Test app',
  ext_modules=[
    Extension('test',
              sources=['test.pyx'],
              extra_compile_args=['-O3'],
              language='c++')
    ],
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}
)
```

Comment: This approach doesn't seem to respect `--inplace`.  See my workaround.

Answer (score 16):

Mike Muller's answer works, but builds extensions in the current directory, not next to the `.pyx` file when `--inplace` is given as in:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

So my workaround is to compose a CFLAGS string and override the env variable:

```
os.environ['CFLAGS'] = '-O3 -Wall -std=c++11 -I"some/custom/paths"'
setup(ext_modules = cythonize(src_list_pyx, language = 'c++'))
```

Answer (score 6):

There's another way to do this, I found it to be the best one from other two presented because with this you still can use all regular `cythonize` arguments in usual way:

```py
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name="Test app",
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        Extension(
            "test_ext", ["test.pyx"],
            extra_compile_args=["-O3"],
            language="c++",
        ),
    ),
)
```