# Remove compile args in Cython

Tags: gcc, cython, setuptools

I want to compile my python project with cython.
I created this setup.py file :

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize

recursive_tree = [file for file in glob.iglob("sample/**/*.py",  recursive=True)]

setup(
    name                                     = 'sample',
    version                                  = sample.__version__,
    packages                                 = find_packages(),
    author                                   = "42",
    description                              = "Cython Sample",
    include_package_data                     = True,
    ext_modules                              = cythonize(
        recursive_tree,
        nthreads=2,
        exclude="setup.py",
        build_dir = "out",
    ),
)
```

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520619/extra-compile-args-in-cython), we can see it's possible to add some extra compile args, but can we do the opposite and remove one?

When I use this command : 
`python setup.py build_ext --inplace` I got this gcc configuration :

`gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.6m -c out/sample/hello.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/out/sample/hello.o`

`gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/out/sample/hello.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6/hello.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

How can i remove the `-g` option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to similar this question: [How may I override the compiler (gcc) flags that setup.py uses by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928110/how-may-i-override-the-compiler-gcc-flags-that-setup-py-uses-by-default) (which I don't think it *quite* a duplicate). They solve a similar problem by adding extra command line arguments to undo the ones that `setup.py` adds by default.

In this case `-g0` ["negates `-g`"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html). Therefore add `-g0` to `extra_compile_args`

```
setup(... # everything as before
      extra_compile_args = ['-g0'])
```

Comment: Get a warning when i'm using `extra_compile_args` in `setup()` and with cythonize. 
I had a good result with using `moduleA = Extension('moduleName', [fileToCompile], extra_compile_args=[-g0])`