# How to remove -pthread compiler flag from cython setup file

Tags: python, cython, compiler-optimization, cythonize

In linux environment, when I run the setup script for cython, I get

```
gcc -pthread -B /apps/.../compiler_compat -Wl,-sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare 
-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/ap......
```

for my case, I want to remove the pthread option. How do I do that thru the cython setup file? I see there are options to add compiler flags but none to remove. My setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

from distutils.extension import Extension

extensions = [Extension("foo",sources = ["foo.pyx"])]                                 

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(extensions))
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984016/remove-compile-args-in-cython) is related but I don't think helps; it's possible the third option from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867041/4657412) might help, but it's a bit extreme losing all the arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @DavidW has pointed out, for many options there is also an option which negates/overrides it and the last option on the command line "wins". So for example adding extra compile option `-Os` would overrule the default setting `-O2` or `-O3`, because `-Os` would come after `-O2` on the command line (`-fwrapv`/`-fno-wrapv` another example for such pairs).

However, `-pthread` has no such "partner" and the only chance to disable it, is to prevent its appearance on the command line altogether. The ways to do it are somewhat hacky, but is this hackiness not the reason we all use python?

`distutils` uses `distutils.sysconfig` to find the right compile/link flags. One possibility would be modify its functionality, so that `-pthread` is filtered out.

I choose [`get_config_vars`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Lib/distutils/sysconfig.py#L467), but there are also other options of course. The plan is simple:

1. wrap `distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars`, so that `-pthread` is filtered out
2. replace `distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars` with the wrapper
3. otherwise, `setup.py` is unchanged

Which leads to the following `setup.py`:

```
# manipulate get_config_vars:
# 1. step: wrap functionality and filter
from distutils.sysconfig import get_config_vars as default_get_config_vars

def remove_pthread(x):
    if type(x) is str:
        # x.replace(" -pthread ") would be probably enough...
        # but we want to make sure we make it right for every input
        if x=="-pthread":
            return ""
        if x.startswith("-pthread "):
            return remove_pthread(x[len("-pthread "):])
        if x.endswith(" -pthread"):
            return remove_pthread(x[:-len(" -pthread")])
        return x.replace(" -pthread ", " ")
    return x

def my_get_config_vars(*args):
  result = default_get_config_vars(*args)
  # sometimes result is a list and sometimes a dict:
  if type(result) is list:
     return [remove_pthread(x) for x in result]
  elif type(result) is dict:
     return {k : remove_pthread(x) for k,x in result.items()}
  else:
     raise Exception("cannot handle type"+type(result))

# 2.step: replace    
import distutils.sysconfig as dsc
dsc.get_config_vars = my_get_config_vars


# 3.step: normal setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

from distutils.extension import Extension

extensions = [Extension("foo",sources = ["foo.pyx"])]                                 

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(extensions))
```

---

I'm not entirely sure, it is a great idea to build without `-pthread` and to load the resulting module in a python-interpreter which is built with `-pthread` - not sure it will not break in some subtle ways and work as intended.

Comment: Works so beautifully like a charm. I am also learning new python tricks from your post besides able to remove the pthread. Thank you so much @ead