# Cython: Casting vector of C++ `std::complex<double>` to C `double complex`

Tags: c++, casting, cython, complex-numbers, memoryview

In Cython, starting from a C++ vector of `std::complex<double>` like this...

```py
# Imports 
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.complex cimport complex as cpp_complex
ctypedef my_complex = cpp_complex[double]

# Code
cdef vector[my_complex] vec
```

... how can I convert this vector to a `double complex` memoryview with the default cython/python's `complex`?

```py
cdef complex[::1] mem_view = ???
```

Alternatively, how can I tell Cython to use C++'s `std::complex<double>` instead of `double complex` as the underneath type of `complex`?

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to extract a pointer to the data with `vec.data()` (returns a complex[double]*), cast it to cython complex*, and cast the array to the fixed vector size:

```py
cdef complex[::1] mem_view = <complex[:vec.size()]>(<complex*>vec.data())
```

For the alternative (setting `std::complex<double>` | cython's `cpp_complex[double]` to be the standard `complex` type), one would have to add some defines to trigger the choice in https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Utility/Complex.c#L56. However, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Note: an answer with better explanations or showing the alternative will be marked as right answer!

Comment: Note2: to return a numpy array, just do `np.asarray(mem_view)`.

Comment: This is probably the right answer. To set the c define you'd use [`extra_compile_flags`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520619/extra-compile-args-in-cython). On Linux this'd be `-DCYTHON_CCOMPLEX=0` (or 1). Note that it's on by default and only affects the C++ compilation stage so you still need the casts in Cython.

Comment: I had the feeling it was like this, the error was raised when `cythonize` was called, meaning that the C++ compiler is not yet involved in it. Good to know!