# Cython: compiler flag -O3 seems deprecated

Tags: python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I used the details provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520619/extra-compile-args-in-cython) to set the optimization flag to `'-o3'`. However, I have the following issue:

- if I use the upper case as `extra_compile_args=['-O3']`, I get the warning:
  `cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'`
- if I use the lower case as  `extra_compile_args=['-o3']`, I get the warning:
  `cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-O3` flag is only supported by gcc and clang. Since you seem to be using the MSVC compiler, you can use the `/Ox` flag, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ox-full-optimization?view=msvc-160) for more details.

Comment: thank you for your reply and as a side note, thanks to that I noticed that actually the compiler flag /Ox (same as /O2 for maximum speed) is the default one used during compilation